# Pros and Cons of IDs at the end of the URL

Tags: rest, url, seo

Some web applications with restful URLs like Foursquare ([https://foursquare.com/v/restaurante-baobab/**4bed589a75feef3b8d0197e6**](https://foursquare.com/v/restaurante-baobab/4bed589a75feef3b8d0197e6)) put ID's at the end of the URL, others like StackOverflow ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**11394640**/pros-and-cons-of-ids-at-the-end-of-the-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394640/pros-and-cons-of-ids-at-the-end-of-the-url)) put them in the middle, just before the title slug..

In your opinion wish one is best for information management and performance?
What is the impact in terms of SEO?

Comment: SO form is more readable to humans. Other preoccupations seem to be very small details in comparison.

Comment: Note: There is nothing "restful" about URLs like Foursquare. ReST isn't about one format of URL over another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many web sites use a resource ID as the real resource identifier in a URL. It corresponds to the number of some database record that is being displayed. But then some sites add a human readable string at the end of the URL.

This is good both for SEO and for users.

1. For users it is a good thing because it gives some indication of what is the resource pointed to by the URL.

It is good for SEO because:

1. adding human readable text at the end of the URL increases CTR ( more people will click on a URL that doesn't end in just a number ).
2. search engines will give some keyword value to the words in the text at the end of the URL.

When you do this to be good for SEO you need to make sure that there is only one URL to each resource. So when you get an access to any URL with a given resource ID number, it should 301 redirect to a URL that contains both the resource ID and the text slug at the end. So if the following two URLs work:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394640/pros-and-cons-of-ids-at-the-end-of-the-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394640
```

The second URL should 301 redirect to the first one.

Comment: What about being part of the slug itself, something like **some-slug-123** or **123-some-slug** ?

Comment: That is fine too. Either of those forms are equally good to using a /. I used the slash form only because I thought it was cute to reference stackoverflow's own urls in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about resources. Resource id's belong after the resource.

> SO.com/questions/**11394640**

In this case, `11394640` is the id if the `question` resource. If it were a specific comment, it might be `SO.com/question/11394640/comment/43`

For the stackoverflow link, the id is actually at the end, it just redirects to the labeled version. `stackoverflow.com/questions/11394640`.

Stack overflow defines urls that are more human-friendly. I can't speak very well to SEO but i suspect the keywords would be of value. [Matt Cutts](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-on-keywords-in-the-url-16976) seems to think they help 'a bit'